# Get relative start and end indices of a word while splitting it Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, string

I have written a function which splits a word based on spaces and preserves punctuation marks.

```
function tokenizeUtterance( utterance )
{
  let spilittedUserText = utterance.toString().match( /[\w-']+|[^\w\s]+/g ); 
  console.log(spilittedUserText);   
}
```

Let's say I have a string of text like: "HELLO, WORLD"

I want to extract the relative start and end positions of the splitted words in a JSON object in the following format.

```
+-------+-------+-----+
| word  | start | end |
+-------+-------+-----+
| HELLO |     0 |   4 |
| ,     |     5 |   6 |
| WORLD |     7 |  11 |
+-------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need here is to:

- Split the `string` into an array of the pair `word` and `index`.
- Use [**`Array#map()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return your custom data for each `word`.

This is how should be your code:

```
function tokenizeUtterance(utterance) {
  let spilittedUserText = [];

  utterance.toString().replace(/[\w-']+|[^\w\s]+/g, function(s, i) {
    spilittedUserText.push({
      word: s,
      index: i
    });
  });
  return spilittedUserText.map(function(w) {
    return {
      "word": w.word,
      "start": w.index,
      "end": w.index + w.word.length - 1
    };
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function tokenizeUtterance(utterance) {
  let spilittedUserText = [];

  utterance.toString().replace(/[\w-']+|[^\w\s]+/g, function(s, i) {
    spilittedUserText.push({
      word: s,
      index: i
    });
  });
  return spilittedUserText.map(function(w) {
    return {
      "word": w.word,
      "start": w.index,
      "end": w.index + w.word.length - 1
    };
  });
}
var string = "HELLO, WORLD";

console.log(tokenizeUtterance(string));
```

Comment: Obviously, this will fail with repeating words.

Comment: This fails, with the same word occuring more than once.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I updated the answer, check it.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively easy way to do it, assuming your output keeps the order of the input string is to simply count the number of characters or positions on each of your output strings:

```
function tokenizeUtterance(utterance) {
  return utterance.toString().match( /[\w-']+|[^\w\s]+/g );  
}

function getStartAndEnd(tokenizedUtterance) {
    let counter = 0;
    const result = [];
    for (const word of tokenizedUtterance) {
        const res = {
            word,
            start: counter,
            end: counter + word.length - 1
        };
        counter += word.length;
        result.push(res);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is what you get back:

```
[
    {"word":"HELLO","start":0,"end":4},
    {"word":",","start":5,"end":5},
    {"word":"WORLD","start":6,"end":10}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it using `indexOf` for every word:

```
function getResult(utterance){
  let spilittedUserText = utterance.toString().match( /[\w-']+|[^\w\s]+/g ); 
  let result = [];
  let currenSearchIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < spilittedUserText.length; i++){
    let startIndex = utterance.indexOf(spilittedUserText[i], currenSearchIndex);
    currenSearchIndex = startIndex;
    let resultItem = {
        word: spilittedUserText[i],
        start: startIndex,
        end: startIndex + spilittedUserText[i].length - 1
    }
    result.push(resultItem);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(getResult('Hello, world Hello')));
```

The output is:

```
[
 {"word":"Hello","start":0,"end":4},
 {"word":",","start":5,"end":5},
 {"word":"world","start":7,"end":11}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace` gives you the match and its offset:

```js
str = "HELLO, WORLD foo HELLO";
result = [];

str.replace(/[\w'-]+|[^\w\s]+/g, (word, offset) => 
    result.push([word, offset, offset + word.length]));

console.log(result);
```